Spring Boot Mail prints anything on system output
I am sending emails with my spring boot server
I am using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:3.3.1
But I get a stupid amount of log output. Is there any way to disable that?
As far as I see, the log is printed to the system output
Example Log
250 OK
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
221 /127.0.0.1 Service closing transmission channel
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 3025, isSSL false
220 /127.0.0.1 GreenMail SMTP Service v2.0.1 ready
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "localhost", port: 3025
EHLO swp73
250-/127.0.0.1
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=localhost, user=awdawdawd@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<awdawdawd@gmail.com>
250 OK
RCPT TO:<664b1c94-3@gmail.com>
250 OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   664b1c94-3@gmail.com
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2024 14:58:41 +0200 (CEST)
From: awdawdawd@gmail.com
To: 664b1c94-3@gmail.com
Message-ID: <1919633455.3.1721393921703@swp73>
Subject: Verify Email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Fixed: open file application.properties, change spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=false

You can modify the logging level to a higher level to reduce the log output. To do that I recommend you read / research how to set log levels and based on what in Spring Boot app

open file application.properties  , change spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=false
